# Terminal is frozen when I install electronjs

Tags: electron

I have a problem when I try to install electron for my project, my terminal is frozen on this message

```
> electron@6.0.10 postinstall C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\node_modules\electron
> node install.js


... and 1 more
```

I uninstalled node 10.16.3 and installed node 12.11.0 and it is still doesn't work

Comment: for how much time did it froze ?

Comment: more than 15 minute

Comment: can you delete node module and `npm install` again

Comment: I tried this and the same problem still there